# Bag of Holding Bomb but with mayonnaise?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I am a DM and one of the PCs has gone through the long-winded effort of close to filling a Bag of Holding with mayonnaise from their *3* Alchemy Jugs. The PC then put *another* Bag of Holding into this "Bag of Mayo", thus creating a portal to the Astral Plane.

What happens to the creamy contents inside this bag?

In the rule book, it states that they will be "scattered" in the Astral Plane, but what would happen to the 60cubic feet of mayonnaise? Will they get send through as one large glob, or will it rain down over an area, or will it just turn some of the atmosphere to mayonnaise?

The PC and I have been trying to figure it out, but we have found nothing yet. I would direct help to solve this greasy mess.

Comment: Clearly, it is actions like this that break off chunks of the Astral and spawn things like the [Semi-Elemental Plane of Ranch Dressing](https://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0802.html)

Comment: Is this roughly equivalent to a question about whether a bagful of Mayo counts as a single discrete object, or several (thousands) squished together? One cannot scatter a single object, after all.

Comment: @Kerrick: A single object can easily *become* multiple objects when subjected to stresses (damage).  e.g. a table is one object for stuff like Animate Object, but a bit of damage can turn it into 4 table legs and one or more large flat pieces.  The required forces are even smaller for a blob of mayo, and would tend to happen naturally during the sucking process.

Comment: Hope it isn't near a Gith creche.  That is egg salad you don't want...

Answer (score 17):

### Up to the DM

Bag of holding says:

> Placing a bag of holding inside an extradimensional space created by a *handy haversack, portable hole*, or similar item instantly **destroys both items and opens a gate to the Astral Plane**.

A bag of holding is the most similar object to another bag of holding, and contains an extradimensional space. Placing one into another one would create the gate. However, this passage says nothing about what happens to the contents. The bag's description also says:

> **If the bag is overloaded, pierced, or torn**, it ruptures and is destroyed, and its contents are scattered in the Astral Plane.

This is slightly different from saying that any time the bag gets destroyed, the contents will be scattered to the astral plane. By creating the portal, the bag is destroyed, but it has not been overloaded, pierced or torn.

Thus, in the absence of guidance about it,  the DM needs to decide what happens if the bag is destroyed by portal-bombing, and what scattered means in case the bag contains liquids, not solids. The dictionary definition of [to scatter](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scatter) contains things such as

> - to cause to separate widely
> - to divide into ineffectual small portions

That suggests it would spray about, not drop out as a single big blob or splash. But ultimately, this is up to the DM.

Comment: With this in mind, the song "It's Raining Mayo" needs to be played in its entirety.